# What are some other options for generating bit grids of size N

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

As is well known, permutations for square bit grids can be calculated using a brute force algorithm where an integer loop from **0...((2^cells)-1)** can be converted into each grid permutation using a bit mask. A few examples:

```
Grid size 2 (4 cells): 0-->15

Grid size 3 (9 cells): 0-->511
```

This works well for grids up to a certain size, but for grids of size 7 and greater the sheer number of loop operations gets into the trillions.

What other options are there?

I already have working code for grids up to size 6 but a quick [Fermi estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem) has a size 7 grid coming out at about 76 years on my workstation with all CPUs at maximum... :-(

**Target application**

Re the actual application of said grids, this would be pretty much the same as for a [Nurikabe puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nurikabe_(puzzle)) but I'm only interested in grids that can be mirrored across their X or Y axis (preferably both). So some suitable patterns might be a diamond (X & Y), the letter D (Y) or letter A (X).

**Existing efficiencies**

Due the vagaries of the target application there are many candidates that can be discarded:

- Those that don't create a cell on the edges of the grid
- Those that cannot be mirrored across the X or Y axis
- Those where cells are isolated

**Sample output (N=4)**

```
Current value is : 28662
 ## 
####
####
 ## 

Current value is : 40953
#  #
####
####
#  #

Current value is : 63087
####
 ## 
 ## 
####

Current value is : 63903
####
#  #
#  #
####

Current value is : 65535
####
####
####
####

Grid size 4, done in 22 milliseconds
```

Comment: Are you trying to generate all possible grids?

Comment: sorry, what is a bit _grid_ ? do you mean bit _array_ ?

Comment: Sorry, yes - bit array.

Comment: @MichaelSPriz Due to what I'm doing with the grids, it is only a fraction of them as I want all shapes to touch the sides of the grids. So given that the last row must have something on it, in reality I can start with the bottom left bit value (e.g. 4096 for a 4x4 grid).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2^n bit masks of size n. You can not possibly hope to generate them all in complexity less than 2^n. You either need an alternative solution to your problem where you don't generate all bit masks, or you will not be able to improve this value.

Comment: I think he is referring to square grids of _width_ 7 - equivalent to a _49_-long bit pattern

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah how come it is 49? What are the dimensions of the grid? According to his own comment OP is referring to bit arrays. Assuming the size of the grid is square you are right of course, but the essence of the answer is still correct

Comment: if it is square then it would be O(4^n) >> O(2^n). but you're right

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah after the last edit by OP I believe he really means square grids. Answer edited

Comment: I've added some of the efficiencies I've already built in to the question

Answer (score 0):

Conservation of information dictates there is no way to generate all array patterns in better than O(2^cells) - you have to consider each case at least once.

However you can optimise it by parallelizing the generation of each array pattern, by using packed bit-sets and maybe SIMD.

There is a technique of systematically generating bit patterns called Maximum Length Sequence. The crucial feature of the generation algorithm is that every possible bit pattern (for a certain number of cells) is generated *EXACTLY ONCE*. It uses XOR to iteratively calculate successive values, which can be optimised (up to reasonable sizes) with SSE/MMX.

Link: http://web.iitd.ac.in/~saifkm/docs/EEL319/Practical/expt3_319.pdf

Comment: Why MLS? Would that be any better than just incrementing?

Comment: @harold good point in general, but specifically to SIMD parallelization, the `xorps` instruction on x86 architectures is faster than `addps`. See http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf

Comment: @harold and of course SSE 4.2+ still does not support summing 128-bit integers - nor is it optimised for integer calculations anyway. whereas XOR is bitwise and does not take into account how data is interpreted

Comment: Why float instructions? I was just thinking paddq (and do two at once), sure it's not 128bit but iterating through 128bit space is hopeless anyway

Comment: @harold as I said xorps does not work on the data as floats - just a bit pattern (and it has no carry). I don't know what you mean by iterating coz SSE does it in parallel

Comment: I know xorps works, but xorps is worse than pxor (pxor has 3 times better throughput). By iteration I just mean the obvious loop we're going to have here, to visit every pattern.

Comment: @harold you're right about `pxor`, but it still works with SSE - you were on about _adding_. and what else is possible apart from visiting every pattern? nothing.

Comment: I don't want an alternative to iteration, I'm just questioning your reasons for wanting to do 128bit things. It will never even explore a billionth of it. There is no scenario in which it makes sense to do it. And yes, adding, namely paddq. Much simpler than MLS, only "downside" is it not exploring 128bit space, which is impossible anyway even if the algorithm theoretically does it.

Comment: @harold my point is it will reduce the constant in O-notation (not the complexity itself) by parallelising bit-wise calculations, rather than looping through each bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in grids that can be mirrored then just generate a quarter or a half of the grid, and mirror it.

**For a 7x7:**

**X and Y mirroring:** Generate all possible X and Y axis permutations 2^(7 + 7 - 1) times all possible 3x3 permutations 2^(3 * 3). Since the 3x3 will be mirrored on the 4 corners thats only 2^13 * 2^9 permutationes 4,194,304 to generate.

**X or Y mirroring:** Generate permutations for 1 axis 2^7 and permutatins for a 3x7 grid 2^21, which is a total of 268,435,456

**For a 8x8:**

**X and Y mirroring:** All of the 4x4 permutationes 2^16 or 65536.

**X or Y mirroring:** All of the 4x8 permutationes 2^32 ~4billion (a modern computers should be able to do this in under a minute).